# Error occurs while calling Scala code in Java in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

I would like to call the following Scala code in Java:

**Scala code**

```
package calculate

import java.io._

class CalculationScala

object CalculationScala {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    def operate(a: Double, b: Double, op: (Double, Double) => Double): Double = (op(a, b))
    println(operate(5, 15, _-_))
  }
}
```

**Java code**

```
package calculate;

public class Calculation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CalculationScala calculationScala = new CalculationScala();
        calculationScala.main(args);
    }
}
```

but the following error occurs.

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function2
    at calculate.CalculationScala.main(CalculationScala.scala)
    at calculate.Calculation.main(Calculation.java:79)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function2
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 2 more
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing scala-library.jar on your runtime classpath.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have downloaded [Scala.msi](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/), installed it and added the `scala-library.jar` located at <install_directory_scala>/lib to the libraries java build path of the Java Project by adding it as an External JAR (right click java project, Java Build Path, Libraries tab, Add External JARs...).

Comment: That is correct. I have accepted and upvoted the answer. Thank you.